# Jquery - remove an element and children when an exact match only

Tags: jquery, dom

I have some html that i need to try and tidy up.   Sometimes the text contains contains paragraph tags that contain only a single break tag inside of them.  This html isn't needed and I want to delete these paragraphs and their child break tags from specific selectors in my html.

I had understood that the following may work

```
$(".selectedClass p>br").remove();
```

But it seems to delete breaks from paragraphs containing breaks among other things.
It's vital my removal only occurs when the html is exactly  `<p><br/></p>`

If the paragraph contains other html/text then its valid and should stay.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
$('p').each(function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).html()) === '<br>') $(this).remove();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LfB3L/)**

Comment: Hi j08691.  Thanks for the comment.  Your code looks ok to me but the jsfiddle doesnt seem to represent the task I have?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The fiddle shows multiple paragraphs with content, only one of which is empty and contains a <br /> tag. The jQuery in my answer removes that empty paragraph tag.

Comment: Sorry your quite right, I just didn't see the one empty paragraph!  Thanks so much!!